Component contains an input of type button with both value and defaultValue props. Input elements must be either controlled or uncontrolle
I am getting an error I theoretically understand, but practically cannot solve.
import React, {CSSProperties, useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {SelectOption, useSelect} from '@mui/base'; 
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next';

export interface DropdownInputProps {
    loading?: boolean,
    label: string,
    options: DropdownOption[];
    placeholder?: string,
    required?: boolean,
    setSelection: (selection: DropdownOption[] | null) => void,
    width?: number,
    readOnly?: boolean,
}

export const DropdownInput = ({
                                  loading,
                                  label,
                                  options,
                                  placeholder,
                                  required,
                                  setSelection,
                                  defaultValue,
                                  width,
                                  readOnly,
                              }: DropdownInputProps) => {

    const menuRef = useRef(null)
    const [value, setValue] = useState<number | null>(null)
    const [listening, setListening] = useState(false);
    const [listBoxVisible, setListBoxVisible] = useState(false);
    const listboxRef = React.useRef<HTMLUListElement>(null);
    const {
        getButtonProps,
        getListboxProps,
        getOptionProps,
        getOptionState,
    } = useSelect({
        listboxRef,
        onOpenChange: () => setListBoxVisible(!listBoxVisible),
        onChange: (event, newValue) => _onChange(newValue),
        open: listBoxVisible,
        options,
        value,
        defaultValue,
    });
    const {t} = useTranslation();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (defaultValue !== undefined) setValue(defaultValue)
    }, [defaultValue]);


    const _onChange = (value: number | null) => {
        setValue(value)
        setSelection(options.filter(option => option.value === value) as DropdownOption[] | null)
    }

    const _renderStringInInput = () => {
      return ...
    }

    const _getSelectedValue = (value: number | null, options: SelectOption<any>[]) => {
        const selectedOption = options.find(option => option.value === value);
        if (selectedOption !== undefined) return t(`${selectedOption.label?.toString()}`)
        return null;
    }

    const _renderListBox = (theme: ThemeProps) => {...}

    const _renderInput = (theme: ThemeProps) => {
        const ariaForId = `:dropdown-input-${guidGenerator()}:`
        const {colors} = theme

        const commonProps: CommonProps = {
            readOnly: readOnly,
            style: {
                color: _getSelectedValue(value, options) ? 'inherit' : colors.lightGreyDarker,
                borderColor: formError ? colors.warningMain : 'inherit'
            },
            placeholder: placeholder ? t(placeholder) : '--',
            className: clsx('input-field', readOnly && 'input-disabled', inputClasses),
            value: defaultValue ? undefined : _renderStringInInput(),
            defaultValue: value ? undefined : _renderStringInInput(),
            type: "button",
            id: ariaForId
        }

        if (formError || dataError) {
            commonProps["aria-invalid"] = "true"
            commonProps["aria-errormessage"] = t(`${ariaErrorMessage}`)
        }

        return <>
            <Text
                style={setLabelColor(theme, formError || dataError, readOnly, labelColor)}
                required={required}
                ariaFor={ariaForId}
                variant={'label'}>
                {label}
            </Text>
            <input
                {...getButtonProps()}
                {...commonProps}
                id={ariaForId}/>
        </>
    }


    return <ThemeContext.Consumer>
        {(theme) =>
            <div
                className={clsx('input-container', containerClasses)}
                style={{width: width, ...style}}>
                {_renderInput(theme)} />
        }
    </ThemeContext.Consumer>
}

And with this I get the warning

Warning: Context.Consumer contains an input of type button with both value and defaultValue props. Input elements must be either controlled or uncontrolled (specify either the value prop, or the defaultValue prop, but not both). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element and remove one of these props.

Which I do not understand. value is not coming from the parent, only defautlValue. Thus, the local state is managed by DropdownInput /> itself. Here
    value: defaultValue ? undefined : _renderStringInInput(),
    defaultValue: value ? undefined : _renderStringInInput(),

I either assign value or defaultValue, depending if there is something in there. So why am I getting this warning?

If you want it to be controlled, set "value" from "defaultValue" and use only "value". since you already did that in useEffect, you can safely use value. If defaultValue comes on initial render, you can set when defining like ....useState(defaultValue).
